# What Account to use for Google Analytics, AdWords, and Adsense

Tags: google-analytics, google-account

I am launching my first web site. I am in the process of setting up google services: Google Analytics, AdWords, and Adsense.

I searched the web and could not find any information about what the best practice related to what account I should use to setup these services?

- create a single purpose Google account

  - create an account for each service
  - create one account to manage all three services
- do you need to create a seperate account for google analytics web and google analytics mobile
- use existing staff google business account
- use keystaff (VP of Marketing) google business account
- how easy is it to change the account that owners the services

Comment: "One Account, All Of Google" (as their motto goes). Basically, you need just one 'universal' Google account, and you can create Google Analytics, Adwords and AdSense accounts, all linked by that single Google account. For GA, you just need the one account and you can create web and mobile properties. I can't speak for business accounts. In GA it's easy to add more admins (owners) to the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One account for all the services should suffice. You can add and/or remove users quite easily to restrict or give new users access should they need it.

One thing I usually do is create one master account for a specific webpage, then I tie it to my own, personal log-in that I use to access these services.

But it all depends on the setup in my opinion. If it is for private use only, I'd say one account should suffice. Google gives you access control if more are needed.